# How to get password back from PublicKeyString in Cryptico

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, cryptico

```
var PassPhrase = "Rosy"; 

var Bits = 1024;
dfRSAkey = cryptico.generateRSAKey(PassPhrase.toString(),Bits);                      
dfPublicKeyString = cryptico.publicKeyString(dfRSAkey);
```

I am able to encrypt "Rosy" and I got public key `dfPublicKeyString`.
I want to get back "Rosy" from my public key `dfPublicKeyString`.
Also how can I get `dfRSAkey` from my public key `dfPublicKeyString`. How can I do it? I am using cryptico.js library. It's an RSA algorithm implementation.

Comment: If the given answer solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) it. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to encrypt "Rosy" and I got public key `dfPublicKeyString`.

No, you're not there yet. The code that you've shown, just generates a RSA private key and extracts the RSA public key from that.

> I want to get back "Rosy" from my public key `dfPublicKeyString`.

That's not possible. The password ("Rosy") that you passed into `cryptico.generateRSAKey()` is actually hashed (mangled) using SHA-256 to produce the seed for the random number generated which is necessary for the RSA key generator to find large primes.

Cryptographic hash functions are not reversible and cryptographic pseudo-random number generators are also generally not reversible. You simply cannot compute the initial password from the finished RSA private key or even from the RSA public key.